# SSL Error while aceesing Webserver through gSoap

Tags: linux, wsdl, gsoap

I want to access a webservice which is built in C#, so i want to make a
webservice client in gsoap.The Webservice link is "https://" , so when i use
wsdl2h tool "wsdl2h -c -o abc.h https://....", i am facing error ,

"cannot connect to https site:no SSL support,please rebuild wsdl2h with SSl or
download the files and rerun wsdl2h"

So i rebuild wsdl2h with command : "make -f MakefileManual secure"
ans was getting the same error message.

When i tried in JAVA I got error that certificate which is provide is not a
valid certificate, so on google i have searched and find solution that i have to
import the certicate and paste in some location.

But for gsoap what should be the procedure ??

Please suggest.